# Is there really a reason for glEnableVertexAttribArray to exist?

Tags: opengl

It seems to me that between `glVertexAttribPointer` (which specifies the attribute index to associate with a particular set of data from a VBO) and `glBindAttribLocation` (which specifies which program vertex attribute variable names the indices are assigned to, there's not really a need to enable or disable the attribute indices themselves. What would be a situation that might require an index to be "disabled"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What would be a situation that might require an index to be "disabled"?

If you want to set a constant vertex attribute value with `glVertexAttrib`, without passing a full blown array.

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glVertexAttrib.xml

Comment: yup. Funny enough, they _could_ have specified that stride=0 would correspond to a constant attribute value. But instead, stride=0 means packed, i.e. stride=size*sizeof(type). That's counter-intuitive if you think about it... (sorry for the babbling)

Comment: @Bahbar: I think APIs that pack "hidden" functionality into functions are counterintuitive. A function like glVertexAttribPointer is only expected to use used for supplying the pointer and its format (at least I'd do). Switching between constant/array access through an extra state is, what I consider consistent and intuitive.

Comment: sure, I'm not arguing that you should hide functionality for the sake of it. But stride=0 _is_ hidden functionality. The effect of what you could imagine stride=0 to be if that wasn't a special case in the spec is indeed a constant attribute. That's all I was saying :D

Comment: I tried using `glVertexAttrib` to set a constant attrib value for use with a shader when I draw using `glDrawElements`: I'm trying to use it to set a color and I can't get it to work (It's black). The same behavior can of course be accomplished using a Uniform but what are some things I can do to check what I'm doing wrong? I did disable the vertex attrib array for the index I'm using.